# Dynamic Variable & Objects

Tags: powershell

Trying to create a script that will read the contents of a directory containing a number of "paired" datasets containing customer data, for each customer there will be 2 datasets with the naming convention appearing consistently in the form: *CustomerNo_DataType.csv* where *CustomerNo* will always be numerical string value.

I've already written a crude version of this script with the customer numbers hard-coded so now I'm trying to improve on that - here's what I've got so far:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem "Path-to-data-files"
$files = $files.FullName
for ($i=0; $i -le $files.Count; $i++){
    $thisFile = $files[$i].Split("\")
```

This leaves me with an array with the full pathname broken down into components so I grab the filename from the last position in the array

```
    $thisFile = $thisFile[$thisFile.Count - 1]
    ...
}
```

I want to use the customer no to create a hashtable, so if the customer no in the filename was 12345 then I want to create a hashtable named `$12345` - I'm not having any issues accessing the value, just not sure how to use it to name something.

Comment: can you post an example that shows the complete filename and the resulting "hash table" that you want to create?  hashtable is a key-value pair where key maps to a value.

Comment: Hi Kiran, sorry last comment was posted incomplete. I want to use the hash table as a translation table, the data to be stored in the hash table will be a 2 column .csv file containing numerical ID's from 2 separate systems. The column which will be used for the "key" fields is the connective field as it appears in both datasets, where a match is found the ID from the second system will be imported into the first dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Split-Path`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849809.aspx) to get the file element of a path:

```
$file = Split-Path 'C:\path\to\some\file.txt' -Leaf
```

Use [`New-Variable`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849913.aspx) if for some reason you need to define a variable name from a variable.

```
$customerNo = '12345'
New-Variable -Name $customerNo -Value @{}
```

However, I wouldn't recommend creating a bunch of dynamically named variables. It's usually a lot easier to handle if you create a "parent" hashtable for the dynamic names. You can have nested hashtables inside it if you need that:

```
$customerNo = '12345'
$customers = @{}
$customers[$customerNo] = @{}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, the New-Variable... approach was exactly what I was looking for, I'm still a bit new to powershell so I'm still doing a few things the long way :)